# Rails list records for a particular day

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create an index.html.erb file that will list records from a table called events.  I'm trying to select records for a particular day.  starts_at is a datetime field in the table.  For example, I'm trying to get all of the records for Monday of this week using:

```
<% @events = Event.where('starts_at.to_date = ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_week.to_date) each do |event| %>
```

But, I don't get records when I should.

One thing it doesn't like is the each statement.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Event.find(:all, :conditions => ["DATE(starts_at) = DATE(?)", DateTime.now.beginning_of_week])
```

or

```
Event.where("DATE(starts_at) = DATE(?)", DateTime.now.beginning_of_week)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing an equals conditional sign.

```
<% @events = Event.where('starts_at.to_date = ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_week.to_date) each do |event| %>
```

Comment: Your correct.  But, it still doesn't work. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AREL.

```
@date = DateTime.now.beginning_of_week
@events = Event.where(starts_at: @date..@date.end_of_day)
```

And that should go in your controller. It's not recommended to do DB queries in your view (not very MVC!).